# Find words in one file and grab the line they are in in another file: Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, file, grep

I am trying to grep out all of the lines in a file that correspond with words found in another file and then make a third, new file with those lines in it.
For example:

```
File 1
rs2132k34hh
rs234hk5kk4
rsklhh32432

File 2
Info   more info   otherstuff     rs2132k34hh somethings
Info   more info   otherstuff    rs234hk5kk4  somethings
Info   more info   otherstuff     rsklhh32432 somethings
Info   more info   otherstuff    rs234hk5kk4  somethings
```

I think that it woud be something along the line of

```
 egrep -l "(\s(rs\S+))" /filethatIamsearching.txt > newfile.txt
```

grep an rs from a file and send to new file

But I know that this isn't everything that should be in the command. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -F -f file1 file2 >newfile.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Do you mind explaining the -F -f command you recommended?

Comment: `-f` read Pattern from a file (file1), `-F` looks Pattern as fixed string. `man grep` will give you more info.

Comment: This won't work if `file2` has a line with `foors234hk5kk4` in it. It will be incorrectly matched. That's why you need `-w` to match words only.

Comment: @dogbane grep is not 100% secure for this, you gave a solution, I can always find exception. e.g what about the keyString not in 4th column, but 3rd? back to your `-w`. if a line in file1 like `.*`, what would happen? you see the necessary of `-F`. or maybe -F and -w better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -wf file1 file2 > file3
```

You can tell `grep` to read patterns from a file using the `-f` option. You can also use the `-w` option to search for whole words only.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. It kept running but nothing was being added to a new file. I let it run for 7 or 8 minutes with no avail.

Comment: Works for me. Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Would it be a problem if the files are fairly large?